# Assigning function output to a macro variable

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Once I have a value in a variable:

```
select max(input(record_date, yymmdd10.)) into :LastDate from My_TABLE;
```

(`record_date` is a `char`, the output of above is `23JUL2017`).

How would I go about manipulating this value? Let's say I wanted to decrement it by a day. When I do:

```
%let LastDate = intnx("day", &LastDate, -1);
```

The value of `LastDate` becomes literally `intnx("day",    21023, -1)`, while I was hoping for `22Jul2017` or `21022`.

Comment: You talk about assigning values to variables, but your code it all about assigning values to MACRO variables. Macro variables are totally different than variables in datasets.

Comment: title corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use SAS functions in macro code then they need to wrapped in the `%sysfunc()` macro function.  Also remember that you don't need to add quotes around string literals in macro code since everything is character strings to the macro processor.

```
%let LastDate = %sysfunc(intnx(day,&LastDate,-1));
```

But that really seems like overkill since dates are just numbers of days. You can just subtract one.

```
%let LastDate = %eval(&LastDate -1);
```

Or if you are using date literals like '23JUL2017'd then you would need to use the `%sysevalf()` function instead.

```
%let LastDate = %sysevalf(&LastDate -1);
```

Of course you could also just subtract the day before making the macro variable.

```
select max(input(record_date, yymmdd10.))-1
  into :LastDate trimmed
  from My_TABLE
;
```